# MSBuild: Specifying a target from the command line

Tags: msbuild

I have an MSBuild task to build a specific project in a solution file. It looks something like this:

```
<Target Name="Baz">
  <MSBuild Projects="Foo.sln" Targets="bar:$(BuildCmd)" />
</Target>
```

From the command line, I can set my `BuildCmd` to either `Rebuild` or `Clean` and it works as expected:

> msbuild /target:Baz /property:BuildCmd=Rebuild MyMsbuildFile.xml
>   msbuild /target:Baz /property:BuildCmd=Clean MyMsbuildFile.xml

But what word do I use to set `BuildCmd` to in order to just build? I've tried `Build` and `Compile` and just leaving it blank or undefined, but I always get an error.

> msbuild /target:Baz /property:BuildCmd=Build MyMsbuildFile.xml
>   Foo.sln : error MSB4057: The target "bar:Build" does not exist in the project.
>
> msbuild /target:Baz /property:BuildCmd=Compile MyMsbuildFile.xml
>   Foo.sln : error MSB4057: The target "bar:Compile" does not exist in the project.
>
> msbuild /target:Baz MyMsbuildFile.xml
>   Foo.sln : error MSB4057: The target "bar:" does not exist in the project.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I understood that you want to build a target with a specific command: Build, Clean, etc.

This is how I would do it.

Create a property to receive your build command, when not specified defaults to Build

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildCmd Condition=" '$(BuildCmd)' == ''">Build</BuildCmd>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After, create the target that will start MSBuild with the specified target in the parameter:

```
<Target Name="Stackoverflow">
  <MsBuild Projects="Foo.sln" Targets="$(BuildCmd)" />
</Target>
```

Then call your MSBuild file with the target and BuildCmd parameter like so:

```
msbuild msbuild.xml /t:Stackoverflow /p:BuildCmd=Clean
```

Just make sure the target exists in the solution or project file.

Comment: I'm trying to build just a specific project within Foo.sln.

Comment: "Just make sure the target exists in the solution or project file.". How do you add a custom target to a sln file?

Comment: Turns out I'm not the only that hit the problem, see the comments form J.Elster here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx

Answer (score 7):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx

/target:targets

Builds these targets in this project. Use a semicolon or a comma to separate multiple targets, or specify each target separately. /t is also acceptable. For example:
/target:Resources;Compile

Comment: The problem is specifying what to do with each target: build, rebuild, clean. Part of the problem is that the term "target" is used on the command line to specify a target within the msbuild file, and again to specify which project to build within a solution file (namespace collision).

Answer (score 2):

The key is conditionalize the BuildCmd property.

```
 <Target Name="Baz">
   <PropertyGroup>
     <BuildCmd Condition="'$(BuildCmd)' != ''">:$(BuildCmd)</BuildCmd>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <MSBuild Projects="Foo.sln" Targets="bar$(BuildCmd)" />
 </Target>
```

This way, if Clean or Rebuild are set, the colon is added.  If nothing is added, BuildCmd will just be blank, defaulting to the Build target.

*Note* - The property group must reside in the target, or it will be overriden when you specify it on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Using CheGueVerra's template, I came up with the following solution:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ProjBuildCmd Condition="'$(BuildCmd)' != 'Build'">:$(BuildCmd)</ProjBuildCmd>
    <SolnBuildCmd Condition="'$(BuildCmd)' != 'Build'">$(BuildCmd)</SolnBuildCmd>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And then instead of using `$(BuildCmd)` directly, I use `$(ProjBuildCmd)` or `$(SolnBuildCmd)` like this:

```
<!-- Build the 'bar' project only -->
<Target Name="Baz">
  <MSBuild Projects="Foo.sln" Targets="bar$(ProjBuildCmd)" />
</Target>

<!-- Build the whole solution -->
<Target Name="Baz2">
  <MSBuild Projects="Foo.sln" Targets="$(SolnBuildCmd)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: This solution is not working for VS10. Do you have any updates on this?

Answer (score -10):

Just edit the sln file yourself and find out - MSBuild is a real easy syntax, just look for targets.

Comment: The .sln file isn't in MSBuild syntax.