# How to use a build variable in installer name

Tags: visual-studio, installation, wix

In my installer project (WiX), I define a preprocessor variable like on the Build tab of the properties pages like so:

```
Version=1.1.0.0
```

For the sake of argument, let's say I can just as easily define it as a variable instead of a preprocessor variable.

My goal is thus:  I would like to use this variable in the installer output name:

```
Me.Common_$(Version)
```

The above, of course, doesn't work - the variable referenced isn't found, so the actual output ends up being `Me.Common_.msi`.  Is there a way to use a user-defined variable in this context?

---

Another viable option would be to rename the MSI file in the post-build events.  However, I still can't access the variable here.

```
ren "!(TargetPath)" "$(TargetName)_$(Version)$(TargetExt)"
```

A solution to either of these methods would work for me.

Comment: This SO post should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191502/include-majorversion-etc-in-filename-outputname-when-building-msi-file-wix-pr

Comment: @BryanJ: It would be ideal not to have to crack open the wixproj file every time I need to update the version. I'd like to change it in the UI and have it transfer.

Answer (score 3):

Find/add these in your .wixproj file, under first PropertyGroup node:

```
<Version Condition=" '$(Version)' == ''">1.1.0.0</Version>
<OutputName>My.Common_$(Version)</OutputName>
```

then, when you compile you can pass Version with "/p" switch, i.e.:

```
msbuild <your.wifproj> /p:Version=1.1.2.0 /t:rebuild
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would do that, by just using WIX.

I would try to use MSBuild and [Target Builds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171462.aspx)

Have a look at my post on SO, for [passing params to MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232052/msbuild-specifying-a-target-from-the-command-line)