# msbuild specific projects configurations. an easy solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, project, config

I have a **solution** file K.sln with many projects in it. Using vs2010.

I need to **compile only three** of those C++ projects, let's say X, Y, Z, T
but **only for some configurations**.

**How do I do that?**

More in detail, I need to

- build X in "Debug" configuration only
- clean Y in "Release" only
- rebuild T in "Static Debug" only
- re-link Z in "Release Optim" ony   (I can live without knowing this)

Is there a way to do it from a single batch file or a command line, or even better creating a simple appropriate msbuild project file? or both way?
**Independently** from how dependencies are set inside the solution file.

Someone can provide a text of the msbuild project for such simple task?

Is it possible to run these task in **parallel**?

Lost already enough time looking around and try to implement it, can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your msbuild.xml file to do all the operations that you want.

You will need:

[Debug or Release configuration](http://code.dblock.org/how-to-do-a-debug-release-or-both-builds-with-msbuild) to be able to set the target builds you need.

[Passing parameters to MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232052/msbuild-specifying-a-target-from-the-command-line) to specify specific targets, like running clean for project "Y" only

Once all the targets and conditionals set you would do something like this:

```
  <Target Name="MakeMyStuff">
    <CallTarget Targets="DebugX" />
    <CallTarget Targets="ReleaseY" />
    <CallTarget Targets="StaticDebugT" />
    <CallTarget Targets="ReleaseOptimZ" />
  </Target>
```

After you need to run a command like:

msbuild msbuild.xml /t:MakeMyStuff (/p:BuildCmd=Clean) if you want to add params

or just one specific

msbuild msbuild.xml /t:DebugX

Good luck